# Как отменить распространение события?

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток!
Суть задачи: выбираем абзац из одного блока и вставляем в другой. далее необходимо определить координаты клика во вставленном абзаце.
Разметка HTML:

```
   <div id="someDiv">
       <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
        Result Here!
    </div>
```

Скрипт на jQuery:

```
  $(function(){
      $('#someDiv p').clone().appendTo('#result');
      $('#someDiv p').hide();
      $('#result').add('p').bind('click', function(event){
        alert('x=' + event.pageX + ', y=' + event.pageY);
      });
    });
```

Вот такая банальщина. работает, но не так, как хотелось бы!координаты выводятся и при клике в абзаце, и при клике в родительском элементе т.е. в `#result`. Cобытие клика "всплывает" по DOM-дереву (что и должно быть). но это распространение хотелось бы остановить. метод `.stopPropagation()` не решает проблемы. Моя уверенность в том, что я сделал что-то не так не покидает меня. 
Подскажите в чём может быть ошибка и как отменить всплытие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял - у вас в определенный div добавляется какой то элемент и алерт нужно что бы срабатывал по клику на него?

В таком случае

```
$('#result').children('p').live('click', function(){});
```

Comment: а вот это решение!
только вот Ваша конструкция не работает. точнее работает, но необходимы изменения. для применения метода live() необходимо указывать ожидаемый набор, который будет в DOM. я изменил так $('#result p.moved').live('click', function(){}); и код начал работать, как нужно мне.

Comment: Да, что то я не подумал что не через .children() надо добираться.

Кстати $('#result p').live('click', function(){}); тоже будет работать.

Comment: так только он и работает) Спасибо Вам!
это я что-то не подумал, что надо привязывать событие на элементы, созданные "на лету"

Comment: Да не за что) Спрашивайте если что.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере `onClick` вешается и на блок `#result` и на абзац

Добавьте вставленному абзацу идентификатор и по нему привяжите событие.

Comment: насколько я помню метод .add() добавляет элемент к набору. то есть возвращает новый набор с указанным элементом.

Comment: Полностью не уверен но дожен возвращатся исходный набор а не модифицированный

вот этот код должен работать так как вам надо - только для вставленного абзаца
$(function(){
      $('#someDiv p').clone().addClass('someClass').appendTo('#result').bind('click', function(event){
        alert('x=' + event.pageX + ', y=' + event.pageY);
      });
      $('#someDiv p').hide();
    });

Comment: возвращается именно модифицированный набор.
Ваш совет хорош, но он, извините, прост. дело в том, что меня интересует именно отмена распространения. я проверял источник события. для уточнения проверки делал 2 клика - первый в абзаце (источник абзац) и в разделе, содержащий абзац (источник раздел). вот мне и стало интересно почему это происходит и как это остановить.

Comment: это не распространение события - оно просто было привязано к лишним элементам 
Это легко проверить - Создайте несколько абзацев за пределами #result - и на них тоже повесится событие

Comment: несколько абзацы создал: один в блоке result и за его пределами. добавил класс в перемещаемый абзац. в итоге событие распространяется на сам блок #result, на абзац постоянно в нём существующий, и на перемещаемый в этот блок абзац. на абзац, находящийся за пределами блока #result - нет.

Comment: Farrock говорит, что метод add() добавляет к ранее найденному #result еще и все абзацы и событие вы вешаете сразу и на див #result и на абзацы. Сделайте так $('#result').children('p') и вешайте событие

Comment: специально для Вас создал дополнительно 2 абзаца: один непосредственно в разделе #result, другой за пределами всех блоков (просто абзац). добавил класс в перемещаемый абзац. получаем в блоке #result два абзаца - один обычный (был изначально в разметке), другой добавляемый с классом. итог: событие клика работает во всех элементах #result. в абзаце за пределами этого блока - нет.

Comment: Еще раз перепроверил - воткнул два абзаца в самом начале вашего примера и в самом конце - с вашим кодом javascript событие срабатывает на всех параграфах